# Edit Control with UNICODE support in MBCS type project

Tags: visual-c++, unicode, mfc

I have old MFC application which support MBCS(Multi Byte Character Set). I have a Edit Control  and CString related to this Control.Now I want that only this control should support UNICODE(UTF-16) character set.

**EDIT:**

In header file :

```
CString m_SerialNO;
```

In cpp file :

```
DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT_SERIAL_NO, m_SerialNO);
```

I can not change the project's character set  property from  `Use Multi-Byte Character Set` to `Use Unicode Character Set`

Comment: You want to keep the project MSCB (which Microsoft is deprecating) but still having one edit control display UNICODE?

Comment: Yes I want like this...

Comment: I tried once the same thing and failed. Just take time to convert it whole to Unicode. It is not that complicated.

Comment: @Dialecticus yes I know it is not complicated but there are some restriction so that I cant change the character set of the project...

Comment: There is one more catch: you must use a font that is able to display the glyphs for the UNICODE characters you need. Not all fonts do that.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the Edit control is created with CreateWindowA all messages will be filtered and converted through the current code page... Even if you use SetWindowTextW, or WM_SETTEXTW a conversion will take place.

Comment: So one could create the edit control dynamically using `CreateWindowW()` and use the API *W functions to set and get the text?

Comment: That is right. But as Long as you are bound to the MBCS MFC you will not be able to solve that. CreateDialogW must also be used. Convert the whole program to UNICODE! That is the best way. You may select some modules that are not translatable and still use MBCS... as Long as tis modles don't use the MFC ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is actually quite easy:

```
// macro to get buffer size in declare character type
#define _countof(array) (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))

// text buffer must be in unicode
WCHAR szBufferW[1024];

// retrieve unicode text in MCBS build dialog
::GetDlgItemTextW(this->m_hWnd, IDC_EDIT1, szBufferW, _countof(szBufferW));

// display unicode text in in MCBS build dialog
::SetDlgItemTextW(this->m_hWnd, IDC_EDIT2, szBufferW);
```